# color the grid in R

Tags: r, colors

I want to color the picture I draw according to the value of z  ,take example like this

```
x<-y<-seq(-2*pi, 2*pi, pi/15)
f<-function(x,y) sin(x)*sin(y)
z<-outer(x,y, f)
#contour(x,y,z,col="blue")
persp(x,y,z,theta=30, phi=30, expand=0.7,col=heat.colors(25))
```

if I want to color this picture in rainbow color or heat.colors  the large the value of z, the dark the color , what should I do,how to control the color set[image]

thank you all

Comment: (-1) Help page of function persp() has an example how to use z values for setting colors (# (4) Surface colours corresponding to z-values).

Comment: Thanks guy I will try my best, as a new in R, the function of each word really confused me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the example in the help , you can use `drape.plot` from `fields` package which by default have colors assigned from a color bar based on the z values.It calls `drape.color` followed by persp and finally the legend strip is added with image.plot.

```
ncol <- 5
library(fields)
drape.plot( x,y,z, col=rainbow(nbcol))
```

[image]